# Make Doctrine use result cache by default

Tags: caching, doctrine, memcached

I'm binding Memcache to Doctrine and it seems I have to `useResultCache` explicitly in every query. Is it possible to make it `true` by default, with the ability to `useResultCache(false)` where it's not needed?

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I'll write up the best answer that comes into my mind.

1) Abstract away your dependency to interface ( i.e. - use dependency injection pattern to inject EntityManager into your class that creates queries and use EntityManagerInterface instead )

Now, either:

a) [ Better, but longer ] Create a new composition-related implementation for EntityManagerInterface, that will proxy calls to original entityManager and will set result cache flag to true:

```
<?php
class CachedEntityManager implements EntityManagerInterface { 

private $proxiedManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $proxiedManager) {   
    $this->proxiedManager = $proxiedManager;    
}

public function createQuery($dql = '') {
    $query = $this->proxiedManager->createQuery($dql);
    $query->useResultCache(true);   
}

[... proxy all the calls forth to proxiedManager ...]

}
```

b) [ Not as good, but shorter ] Extend the EntityManager class and override the createQuery. Remember that this in general is not a good practice and you should definitely not write anything in that class anymore but instead refactor into a) :

```
<?php
class CachedEntityManager extends EntityManager { 

public function createQuery($dql = '') {
    $query = parent::createQuery($dql);
    $query->useResultCache(true);   
}

}
```

Comment: @Jarrett quoting from EntityManager DocBlock: **You should never attempt to inherit from the EntityManager: Inheritance is not a valid extension point for the EntityManager. Instead you should take a look at the {@see \Doctrine\ORM\Decorator\EntityManagerDecorator} and wrap your entity manager in a decorator.** It still doesn't answer **why** though.

Answer (score 9):

Create a wrapper class/function that explicitly sets `useResultCache(true)` and use that everywhere instead of the native function.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to modify every query. This solution would still require it, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can hack the Doctrine core a little by setting the default value of `$_useResultCache` to `TRUE` in `\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery`. This will make all queries use the resultCacheDriver by default, and you can easily turn the cache off for individual queries using `$query->useResultCache(FALSE)`

It's a useful little hack that saves you a lot of typing, but be careful; I've found that the caching driver won't cache lazy-loaded associations that haven't been initialized (which is obvious now I think about it). Sometimes it's safer to just turn result caching on for each individual query.

Comment: I realise that suggesting to hack the core might have earned me the down-vote, but [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886647/make-doctrine-use-result-cache-by-default/7302637#comment6781738_5886767) suggests that they don't want to have to re-write every query. If this is the case, hacking `AbstractQuery` is the easiest solution.