# Why doctrine 2 goes to DB in repeated queries?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

when I do

```
$objectRepository = $objectManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class);
$myEntity = $objectRepository->findOneBy(["some_attribute" => $someValue]);
$myEntity = $objectRepository->findOneBy(["some_attribute" => $someValue]);
```

Doctrine is performing 2 queries instead of just 1:

```
151205 19:32:58  1265 Query SELECT ... WHERE t0.some_attribute = 'some_value' LIMIT 1
151205 19:32:59  1265 Query SELECT ... WHERE t0.some_attribute = 'some_value' LIMIT 1
```

I want to avoid duplicate queries with a cache, I configured it:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
       ...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: array

        result_cache_driver: array
        query_cache_driver: array
        second_level_cache:
            enabled: true
            log_enabled: true
            region_cache_driver: array
```

With `array` cache, because I just want to avoid duplicated queries in the same request.

But it isn't working, Doctrine stills performing duplicated queries instead of using a cache...

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because `doctrine` is not set up to cache stuff by default. To make your query to be cached you need to set it manually:

```
$entity = $objectRepository
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where(...)
    ->getQuery()
    ->useQueryCache(true) //setting query to be cached
    ->useResultCache(true) //setting result to be cached
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

To make doctrine cache stuff by default check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886647/make-doctrine-use-result-cache-by-default?answertab=active#tab-top) question
Also make sure that you are in valid environment (caching is often enabled only in `production` env)